# TestNG custom reporting for webservice (soapUI)

Tags: java, testng, soapui

I have a soapUI project which can be kicked off from Java TestNG.xml. I have numerous assertion for each steps. Currently if I run my project from TestNG, all it shows is that if it is passed or failed. To debug this, I have to manually run testsuite in soapUI.

What I would like to do is to set up a custom report so that I can get following.
Report should contain:
- Duration to run each testcase
- For each step, which soap request did I send
- soap response

I found this: http://elekslabs.com/2015/02/make-the-most-of-your-test-report.html

I tried to use ATU but it looks like it is using selenium. I use Maven, TestNG, Java code, and soapUI.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
GV

Answer (score 0):

TestNG is already providing all you need about duration via [logging reporter](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-reporters).

TestNG is providing a [API](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-reporter-api) to add what you want to the report too.

What you need to find now is how you can catch Request/response from soap.